# 2 sets of radio buttons with same IDs

Tags: html, forms, input

Is it possible to have 2 groups of radio buttons that share an ID? I can't seem to get them to play nice with each other.

Demo: http://abenjamin765.github.io/slidemenu/

```
<input type="radio" name="set-one" id="radio-one">
<input type="radio" name="set-one" id="radio-two">
<input type="radio" name="set-one" id="radio-three">

<input type="radio" name="set-two" id="radio-one">
<input type="radio" name="set-two" id="radio-two">
<input type="radio" name="set-two" id="radio-three">
```

Cheers!

Comment: IDs **must** be unique.

Comment: And now: perhaps you could explain why you want elements to share a unique identifier? I suspect that the problem you're trying to solve can be solved more easily than this route.

Comment: IDs must be unique. If you want, try assigning them the same class and for the class, do actions on the inputs.

Comment: I'm using radio buttons as tabs in a nav bar rather than a radio selection. It needs to be flexible enough to be on the page multiple times without conflicts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The ID attribute **must** be unique. The ID attribute represents a unique identification for that individual element.

From the [HTML5 specification's `id` attribute section](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute):

> ## 3.2.5.1 The id attribute
>
> The `id` attribute specifies its element's unique identifier (ID).
>
> **The value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's home subtree** and must contain at least one character.

If you want to let them share a reference (for styling purposes, for instance), you can instead use the `class` attribute:

```
<input type="radio" name="set-one" class="radio-one">
<input type="radio" name="set-one" class="radio-two">
<input type="radio" name="set-one" class="radio-three">

<input type="radio" name="set-two" class="radio-one">
<input type="radio" name="set-two" class="radio-two">
<input type="radio" name="set-two" class="radio-three">
```